# Simple input and output buffer example with FreeRTOS in c

Tags: buffer, fifo, freertos

I am trying to implement two tasks running in FreeRTOS to transfer data between them via a communication interface. To avoid the concurrency problem, I have used mutex to protect the shared resource. From one side of the task, I am receiving the data perfectly. From the other side of the task I am not getting the output properly. I attach my code snippet and the serial output below.

code snippet

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "semphr.h"
#include "task.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t i;
static uint16_t p1, p2 = 0;

typedef struct{
        char src_buffer[20];
        char dst_buffer[20];

}communication_interface;


SemaphoreHandle_t mutex;
SemaphoreHandle_t dst_mutex;

void ble_bio_test_application_task(void* params)
{
    communication_interface* interface = (communication_interface*)params;

    for (;;) {
        bio_send_to_the_network_task(interface, "PING", 5);
        bio_send_to_the_network_task(interface, "HELLO", 6);
        bio_send_to_the_network_task(interface, "WOW", 4);
        bio_send_to_the_network_task(interface, "WORD", 5);
        bio_send_to_the_network_task(interface, "AB", 3);

        char application_buffer[20] = { 0 };

        bio_recv_from_the_network_task(interface, application_buffer, 5);
        printf("T1: %s\n", application_buffer);

        bio_recv_from_the_network_task(interface, application_buffer, 7);
        printf("T2: %s\n", application_buffer);

        bio_recv_from_the_network_task(interface, application_buffer, 8);
        printf("T3: %s\n", application_buffer);

        bio_recv_from_the_network_task(interface, application_buffer, 3);
        printf("T4: %s\n", application_buffer);

    }
}
void ble_bio_test_network_task(void* params)
{
    communication_interface* interface = (communication_interface*)params;


    for (;;) {

        char network_buffer[20] = { 0 };

        bio_read_from_application_task(interface, network_buffer, 5);
        printf("T5: %s\n", network_buffer);


        bio_read_from_application_task(interface, network_buffer, 6);
        printf("T6: %s\n", network_buffer);


        bio_read_from_application_task(interface, network_buffer, 4);
        printf("T7: %s\n", network_buffer);


        bio_read_from_application_task(interface, network_buffer, 5);
        printf("T8: %s\n", network_buffer);


        bio_read_from_application_task(interface, network_buffer, 3);
        printf("T9: %s\n", network_buffer);


        bio_write_to_the_application_task(interface, "PONG", 5);
        bio_write_to_the_application_task(interface, "DIALOG", 7);
        bio_write_to_the_application_task(interface, "ABCDEFG", 8);
        bio_write_to_the_application_task(interface, "HI", 3);
    }
}

void bio_send_to_the_network_task(communication_interface* interface, char* buffer, uint8_t len)
{
    if (xSemaphoreTake(dst_mutex,portMAX_DELAY) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

             interface->dst_buffer[p1++] = buffer[i];
            }
        p1 -= len;
        xSemaphoreGive(dst_mutex);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500);
}

void bio_read_from_application_task(communication_interface* interface, char* buffer, uint8_t len)
{
    if (xSemaphoreTake(dst_mutex, portMAX_DELAY) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = interface->dst_buffer[i];
        }

        xSemaphoreGive(dst_mutex);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500);
}

void bio_write_to_the_application_task(communication_interface* interface, char* buffer, uint8_t len)
{
    if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, portMAX_DELAY) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                interface->src_buffer[p2++] = buffer[i];

        }
        p2 -= len;
        xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500);
}

void bio_recv_from_the_network_task(communication_interface* interface, char* buffer, uint8_t len)
{
    if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, portMAX_DELAY) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = interface->src_buffer[i];
        }
        //p2 -= len;
        xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
T5: PING
T6: HELLO
T7: WOW
T8: WORD
T9: AB
T1: 
T2: PONG
T3: DIALOG
T4: ABCLOG
```

As you can see, the data is not receiving properly from the second task to the first task. T1 is not receiving any data, I think before writing into the src_buffer, the first task reads from the second ask which has nothing to read out.  I am not understanding what went wrong here. Someone can help me out with what went wrong here.

Thanks in advance.